# Can TFS11 connect to Google code?

Tags: svn, tfs, google-code

I'm currently using TFS11 for the project I'm working on.

I'd like to pull a project ([AntiSamy](http://code.google.com/p/owaspantisamy/source/browse/#svn/trunk/dotNet/current/source/owaspantisamy%253Fstate%253Dclosed)) down from GoogleCode.

Will I *NEED* to install e.g. TortoiseSVN to connect to the project and save it in my file system, or can TFS connect to GoogleCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the MSDN page about [Team Foundation Server Migration and Integration Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//bb840033.aspx), they present [Timely Migration](http://www.timelymigration.com/) as a tool that

> Migrates version control data from Subversion to Team Foundation Server and also provides a two-way synchronization on the migrated data.

So you should have a look at what they can offer.

Regarding free alternatives, you could use [SvnBridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/) in order to be able to use the same client (TortoiseSVN for example) for both your TFS and SVN servers.

Eventually, you will have to look deeper in [TFS Integration Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe) and [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/). [This page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/06/06/toc-tfs-integration-tools-blog-posts-and-reference-sites.aspx) and [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/05/11/tfs-integration-tools-where-does-one-start-part-1.aspx) seems to be good entry points.